# Merge as Single Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

```
SELECT CITY,CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) AS CHARLENGTH 
FROM STATION 
ORDER BY CHARLENGTH ASC 
LIMIT 1;

SELECT CITY,CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) AS CHARLENGTH 
FROM STATION 
ORDER BY CHARLENGTH DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
##DROP TABLE STATION;
CREATE TABLE STATION (CITY VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES ('aaaaaaa');
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES ('bbbbbbb');
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES ('cccc');
INSERT INTO STATION VALUES ('dd');
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT CITY,CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) AS CHARLENGTH FROM STATION ORDER BY CHARLENGTH ASC, CITY LIMIT 1) A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT CITY,CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) AS CHARLENGTH FROM STATION ORDER BY CHARLENGTH DESC, CITY  LIMIT 1) B
```

Output:

```
    CITY    CHARLENGTH
1   dd  2
2   aaaaaaa 7
```